# How can I sum up the totals of product prices based on the users cart?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a list of items on a users cart, and need to find out a way to add up the price for each product. It'll have to first check the product IDs from the cart table for each user, and then check the product table to get the price.

This is the code to grab the product information and the cart items (for listing purposes):

```
        $grabProducts = $connect->prepare("SELECT `product`, `quantity` FROM `cart` WHERE `session` = ? ORDER BY `id` DESC");
        $grabProducts->bind_param('s', $sessionCode);
        $grabProducts->execute();
        $grabProducts->bind_result($productId, $productQuantity);
        $grabProducts->store_result();

while($grabProducts->fetch()) {
        $grabProductInformation = $connect->prepare("SELECT `name`, `description`, `shortname`, `game`, `server`, `price` FROM `products` WHERE `id` = ?");
        $grabProductInformation->bind_param('i', $productId);
        $grabProductInformation->execute();
        $grabProductInformation->bind_result($productName, $productDescription, $productShort, $productGame, $productServer, $productPrice);
        $grabProductInformation->store_result();
        $grabProductInformation->fetch();
            $grabProductInformation->free_result();
            $grabProductInformation->close();
}
```

What is the best way to get a total of the prices from each item?

Comment: Crazy little called `SUM()`?

Comment: I'm aware of sum, but not sure how to look it through the first query and the second. Since it needs to be used based on both... Not sure if you understand what I mean. It grabs the IDs from one and then the prices from another. How would the query look?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your loop, after you grab the product prices from the database use a variable to hold the total value and when your loop ends you will have the sum of all the prices in your result.

```
$sum=0;    
while($grabProducts->fetch()) {
// existing code here
$sum+=$productPrice;
}
echo $sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(products.price) from cart,products where cart.product=products.id and cart.session=?
```